# Wampserver - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

After reinstalling wampserver and copying database folders from \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\ to new \wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data, i get this error:

> **Error establishing a database connection**

please kindly help out.!

Answer (score 0):

First Just check mysql server is running.Can you log in to MySQL with the mysql command line ? Let's start there to see if the MySQL service is running.

Sometimes it maybe a conflict with skype.If that so,first logout from the skype & the shutdown that process and after that click and restart the wamp server.

Comment: SKYPE can conflict with Apache i.e. port 80 and not MySQL port 3306.